# A function does not work with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to send an array from a server that contains all the IDs of the users when someone connects on the server using socket io. Apparently, the emitting part seems to work properly, but the receiving part is not responding at all.

```
io.sockets.on('connection',
// here's the on connection event
function (socket) {
  i++;
  ids[i]=socket.id;
  console.log("We have a new client: " + ids[i]);
  socket.broadcast.emit('setid', ids);
}
/////that is the emitting part
```

now this is the receiving part:

```
 socket.on('setid',
   function(ids) {
  console.log(ids);
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `socket.broadcast.emit('setid', ids);` to `socket.broadcast.emit('setid', {idArr:ids});` and `console.log(ids.idArr);` on the receiving function.

as someone asked,

Sever

```
io.on('connection',
// here's the on connection event
function (socket) {
  let i = 0;
  let ids = [];
  i++;
  ids[i]=socket.id;
  console.log("We have a new client: " + ids[i]);
  socket.broadcast.emit('setid', {
    idArr:ids
  });
}
```

Client

```
socket.on('setid', function(ids) {
  console.log(ids.idArr);
 }
);
```

As a side note as It wasn't completely clear here, using `socket.broadcast.emit` shall emit to all clients **except the socket sending the emit** So until you open another client instance it won't emit.

Comment: Your code is ok, show us the entire code of the client please. Are you sure that the client does not receive the array?

Comment: I've updated my answer @mk12ok Going to quickly create a dummy project to test it, even though I'm fairly sure this should work.

Comment: It is perfectly ok to send the array `ids`. Your solution to send the object `{idArr:ids}` will work too but why make things complicated?

Comment: If you view any of the documentation for socket.io they always send information using this format so it's easier to distinguish. Though you are correct there are no significant benefits unless you plan to send multiple things. I also verified that my solution does work as well :-)

Comment: I think you may be right when you say that Khalil should open another client to test. We don't have full info about the problem

Comment: Very true, @mk12ok thanks for keeping me on my toes here!

Comment: @mk12ok yeah, i've tried to put a console.log with a message with the evnt like this: socket.on('setid',console.log("msg"));  and i perfectly received the message, but when i try to put it in a function like this: socket.on('setid',function(ids){console.log("msg");}); it does not work anymore

Comment: I will try to write something very similar to your setup, give me a minute, I can't see any bug in your code

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following example, it is very simple, just the `socket.io` server and the `socket.io-client` client (you may have to run `npm install socket.io-client` first):

khalil-server.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3001);
var ids = [];
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    'use strict';
    ids.push(socket.id);
    console.log("We have a new client: " + socket.id);
    socket.broadcast.emit('setid', ids);
});
console.log('Server started at port 3001');
```

khalil-client.js

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3001');
socket.on('setid', function (ids) {
    console.log(ids);
});
```

Start the server with `node khalil-server` and as many clients as you can with `node khalil-client` (you will have to run at least two client instances because we use the `socket.broadcast.emit`). It just works. Please show us more of your code and we will try to find a bug.